# Customizing Notes and Attachments

Tags: visualforce, attachment

I have a field called marks on an object called Students. In Students object i have a related list called "Notes and Attachments" . In order to upload a document I have to do this using the "Attach file" and upload the marks memo of the student.

Now I had to include another custom field on the Students object called Attendance. Now my question is when a user is trying to upload either of marks or attendance files is there any way we can customize using VF so that the system asks the user to choose which file they want to upload (more like a pick list) and when they select it the name of the file should be populated in the custom field's name.

For example:- If the user selects on Notes & Attachments " and proceeds through the process of uploading the documents the system should ask if the user wants to upload "marks" or"Attendance" a picklist type. So is there any method to make a change to the standard functionality ?

If yes to the above question, after clicking on "Notes and Attachments" if the user opts to upload "marks" and selects this file "Marks sheet of xyz.txt"  the custom field "marks" should have the name "Marks sheet of xyz".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add such functionality to the standard behaviour of Notes and Attachments.You would have to create your own VF page and upload attachments through it and attach it to your record.Visit the below link for clarity:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096iUIAQ